# How do I render html div into my base template?

Tags: python, django

I use urllib and BeautifulSoup to scrap html from Nasdaq. How do I render the html result into view.

```
def data(request, symbol):
   context_dict = {}

   NASDAQ = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/{}/financials?query=income-statement".format(symbol)

   import urllib.request
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
   headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, }
   assembled_request = urllib.request.Request(NASDAQ, None, headers)  # The assembled request
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(assembled_request)
   html_data = response.read()  # The data u need

   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
   genTable = soup.find_all("div", class_="genTable")

   context_dict['genTable'] = genTable

   return render(request, 'data.html', context_dict)
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_content %}
    <h1>{{ symbol }}</h1>
    {% if genTable %}
        {{ genTable }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The template above will add the actual html string (`<html></html>...`) into the view:

```
NASDAQ
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>MYSTOCK:100$</body>
</html>
```

I would like to embed the html into my template so I get this result:

```
NASDAQ
MYSTOCK:100$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code django defaults to safe defaults, escaping the html and javascript contained in the variable `genTable` to avoid security issues.

To tell django that the variable contains html and javascript that should be executed as part of your page you need to use  [`{% autoescape %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_content %}
    <h1>{{ symbol }}</h1>
    {% autoescape off %}
        {{ genTable }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

However this will put the contents in your website as if it were your code. It's not recommended to put unsanitized code from third parties in your website.

EDIT:
In the comments the useful remark was made by @IanAuld that the built in filter [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) has the same effect:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_content %}
    <h1>{{ symbol }}</h1>
    {{ genTable|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. How do I get rid of the [ ] in the return genTable?

Comment: find_all returns a list probably. `Try genTable = soup.find_all("div", class_="genTable")[0]`